# Upload runs multiple times

Tags: php, upload

I have an application running which allows users to upload .zip files.
Everything runs smoothe, but somehow the upload runs multiple times.
I googled, searched stackoverflow, but as i read my code it does not run the do_upload() function multiple times, just once in the if clause.

As i understand the upload library, 
$this->upload->display_errors()
and
$this->upload->data()
does not run the upload again, am i right?

My controller:

```
    function upload()
{
    $this->checkAuth();
    $config['upload_path'] = '.\files\zipped\\';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $config['max_size'] = '200000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('\upload\v_import', $error);

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('\upload\v_upload_sucess', $data);
        $this->parse();
    }
}
```

my view:

```
    <?php echo $error;?>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('import/upload');
    ?>

    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="100" />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

    </form>
```

my success view:

```
    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
    <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <p><?php echo anchor('import', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>
```

Comment: What "upload library" are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
this one

sorry for not beeing specific.

Comment: btw.: printing out something inside the function upload() does print out only once, confirming this function runs only once.

Comment: How do you know the upload occurs twice? are you getting two versions of the same file uploaded under different names?

Comment: no, only one file with the correct name.
But i see it in the browser.
i use chrome, so it tells me in the lower left corner the percentage of the upload. When it reaches 100% it starts again.
Thats what makes me somehow think that maybe the CI_Upload Class does something which i dont dont understand, maybe peaks at the file first and then does the actual upload when the file is validated or something like that? Anyhow, reading through the code does not confirm that.

Comment: i added this:  
'convert_dots' => FALSE  
to the  
$defaults array  
in  
public function initialize($config = array())  
in the CI_Upload Class to prevent codeigniter from converting dots to underscores, the uploaded files filenames contain several dots. Beneath that, the class is untouched.

Comment: Back when I used to upload files via my own Flash apps there used to be the possibility of the upload client sending 2 requests in order to check headers and server response. Whilst the first request only sent the headers, it still counted as two requests... maybe this is what you are seeing? Are you testing with a large file? obviously if you see the upload take the same amount of time each time with a large file then it is definitely uploading twice, however if the first request is quick and the second longer I would guess this is what is happening, and is what Chrome does. Could test w/ FF?

Comment: Thanks!
But unfortunately it takes the same time. The same with large (>1mb <10mb) or smaller files.
I´ll check with FF, one second...

Comment: firefox:
- sending request (takes a while)
- waiting for server (the server does stuff with the file)
- result page

BUT: the sending request in ff takes longer then 1 upload in chrome. maybe it actually also does the upload miltiple times

tested in chrome again, now it uploaded it 3 times! I dont get it...

Comment: do you have access to your server's logs at all? if so, you should have a look at the last few requests and see what you are getting... on top of that you could inspect the request from the client side using FireBug's net tab or Chrome's net tab on it's console.

Comment: just to not let this topic open like this...

I did not really figure out why it behaved like that but i got rid of it.

When i do not check for authorization, it loads once less. I dont understand why, it is just a function checking for some post data, returning true or redirecting if not authorized.

Another loading was done sometimes because of a server issue.

So, Thank you very much guys for trying to help!